# SFTP to send file with bash script

Tags: file, bash, send, sftp

I'm using key authentication, so password is not an issue.  I have a file whose name I know and I simply want to send it to another machine over sftp.

I tried searching but couldn't find this (seemingly simple) question anywhere.  Perhaps my Google-fu is simply failing me today.

In short: I'm on my local machine, want to send a file (test.txt) to a remote machine.  Authorized keys are already provided.  Basically I want to automate these three steps:

```
sftp root@remote:/root/dropoff
put test.txt
quit
```

Is there a simple bash command I can use to automate this?  The only option I've seen is using a bash script to perform the put/quit and using the -b option to run it.  Is there anything cleaner than that?  (I'm not interested in using any other applications/tools.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You said that you are not interested in other tools, but `scp` is a much better choice for unattended file transfers. Here is an scp example:

```
scp test.txt root@remote:/root/dropoff
```

Comment: does not work with sftp servers that only support sftp.  error "exec request failed on channel 0"

Comment: SCP is a different protocol and it is not available in all cases. So on SFTP only servers you will get error `This service allows sftp connections only.`

Answer (score 48):

I know this is an old one, but you can also pass arguments to a command with a [Here Document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

#### You can put the following into a script:

```
# The following is called a HERE document
sftp <user>@<remote> << SOMEDELIMITER 
  put test.txt
  ... # any commands you need to execute via sftp
  quit
SOMEDELIMITER
```

each additional command will be fed into the command preceeding the `<<` and `SOMEDELIMTER` can be anything you want it to be.

scp is a great option, however sftp was the only tool I was able to get working when pushing from linux to windows and you're stuck using FreeSSHD in service mode!

Comment: i tried \ or \\ as SOMEDELIMTER, it doesn't work, use @ it is OK

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how sftp was configurable when this question was asked. Anyway, 6 years later, you can put sftp-commands like PUT into a file and then reference this file in your initial sftp-call. The makes the whole process completely non-interactive and easily configurable:

```
sftp -i /path/to/ssh-key -b /path/to/sftp-commands.txt root@remote:/root/dropoff
```

....Where sftp-commands.txt just contains

```
put test.txt; quit
```